# Using SharePoint Site across domains 

Tags: domain, user-accounts, authentication

We have a SharePoint site in a domain where most of the users are located.

A few users are in a different domain.

Is it possible to give these users access to the site? Does it require a trust between the domains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an article I wrote a while back to pull together resources for supporting multiple domains.  http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/supporting-multiple-active-directory-domains

Answer (score 1):

If you want the additional users on the different domain to use Windows authentication,then yes you will need a trust relationship between the domains. You could also use Forms Based Authentication for the subset group if the trust is not an option for you.